# Сохранить значение поля в cookie

Tags: php, jquery, cookie, jquery-form

Есть скрипт обработки формы

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").submit(function() {
        let count = $('#number');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "order.php",
            data: $(this).serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            count.val(parseInt(count.val())-1);
            $("#form").trigger("reset");
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Возле формы есть счетчик свободных мест
И есть функция, которая при успешной отправке, уменьшает значение счетчика на 1

```
let count = $('#number');
count.val(parseInt(count.val())-1);
```

Подскажите как можно сохранить значение #number для пользователя, который отправил форму. Чтобы он видел значение #number - 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    $(document).ready(function() { // При загрузке документа

        if(localStorage.getItem('val')){ // Проверяем если ли значение в localstorage
            $('#number').val(localStorage.getItem('val')) // Если есть вписываем в поле с id = number
        }

        $("#form").submit(function() {
            let count = $('#number');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "order.php",
                data: $(this).serialize()
            }).done(function() {
                count.val(parseInt(count.val())-1);
                $("#form").trigger("reset");
                localStorage.setItem('val', count.val()); // После отправки сохраняем в localstorage значение.
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Благодарю! Работает)